# AWS - how to pass DynamoDb table data to Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Below is my customer `table` in `DynamoDb`

```
name: string
```

I have linked a trigger that would call Lambda function that in turn calls my app Endpoint which would do data transformation & save in SQL DB

Whenever I am adding any record or updating record in the above table, I can see that Lambda function is getting called. but not sure how can I capture the table data.

I need to capture the `name` value of the `customer` dynamoDb table via Lambda function which I can pass to my Endpoint.

Newbie to this. So please excuse if it's too simple. But couldn't find the info that could drive this for me.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean triggered by DynamoDB stream?

Comment: @jogold yes. correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Lambda function will receive a *DynamoDB Streams Record Event* (see [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html) for an example event).

You are going to map/loop over the `Records` key where you will find objects with `eventName: INSERT`. Inside the `dynamodb` key you will find the table data that you should process in your Lamdba function's code.

```json
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventID": "1",
      "eventVersion": "1.0",
      "dynamodb": {
        "Keys": {
          "Id": {
            "N": "101"
          }
        },
        "NewImage": {
          "Message": {
            "S": "New item!"
          },
          "Id": {
            "N": "101"
          }
        },
        "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES",
        "SequenceNumber": "111",
        "SizeBytes": 26
      },
      "awsRegion": "us-west-2",
      "eventName": "INSERT",
      "eventSourceARN": eventsourcearn,
      "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb"
    }
  ]
}
```

In your case, the data should be located at `Records[0].dynamodb.NewImage.name.S`

If working with Node.js and mixed types in your table, I suggest using [`AWS.DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/Converter.html#unmarshall-property) which converts a DynamoDB record into a JavaScript object. It allows you to do something like this:

```js
const newImage = DynamoDB.Converter.unmarshall(event.Records[0].dynamodb.NewImage);
```